# Calling method from within the main in c#

Tags: c#, n-queens

I have practised in C++ . It is a solution for 8-Queens that outputs all the 92 possible solutions.

[C++ code example: What makes this loop so many times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235811/c-code-example-what-makes-this-loop-so-many-times)

Then I have written it in C#. Here it is, But I have an error at the very end.

```
                int[,] state = new int[8, 8];
                solve_state(state, 0); // Error: an object reference is required for non-//static field,method
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post _all_ the relevant code? Where is `solve_state` defined?

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring the `solve_state` method as static.

```
       // ↓
private static void solve_state(int[,] state, int count)
{
    // method implementation here
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Code is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you declared the `solve_state` as an instance (i.e. non-static) method. However, you cannot call an instance method without a reference to an instance of the parent class. Instead, make the `solve_state` method static, like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        int[,] state = new int[8, 8];
        solve_state(state, 0); 
        ...
    }

    private static void solve_state(int[,] state, int x)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)